# Why doesn't my program produce any output?

Tags: scheme

I am looking to write a Scheme function `numofatoms` that determines the number of elements in a list.
For example, `(numOfSymbols  '((1 3)  7  (4  (5  2)   ) )`  should return `6`.

What I have so far:

```
;(1 3) 7 (4(5 2)) the list
(define (numofatoms lst) ;defining a numofatoms function
(define (flatten x) ;defining a flatten function
  (cond ((null? x) '())
        ((pair? x) (append (flatten (car x)) (flatten (cdr x))))
        (else (list x))))
  (length (flatten lst)))
(numofatoms '((1 3) 7 (4(5 2)))); calling the function
```

After defining `numofatoms` and `flatten` I don't see any errors but the program is not working. It doesn't produce any outputs.

Comment: Might it be the missing `)` in the end?  Also the ident of calling the function make it look like it is a part of the definition. It should be on the same level as `define`.

Comment: @Sylwester I fixed the indention and the missing `)` and that caused a new error!

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `*** ERROR: unbound variable: flatten`. Note that `flatten` is not a standard Scheme procedure; where have you defined it?

Comment: @adabsurdum I defined it and I dont get errors nor an output

Comment: @RoboC -- I have rolled back the edits you made after the question was answered. It is considered bad etiquette on SO to edit questions in such a way that existing answers are invalidated; your edits completely changed the code in such a way that it no longer worked, and the question that was asked and answered was removed from the body of the post. I also edited the title which reflected the state of the question before other issues were fixed to get to the question that was answered. If you have a new question, post it separately so that it will be more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code works fine if you load it and call `numofatoms` from the REPL. I presume that OP is either calling `load` from the REPL or running the code as a script from the command-line, and when either of these is done OP sees no output. The REPL evaluates and *prints* results (hence the *P*), but when you `load` code that isn't necessarily what happens.

When an expression is evaluated in the REPL, the value to which the expression evaluates is printed. There may be an expectation that the value of the final expression in a file will be printed when the file is loaded into the REPL, but that expectation will not be rewarded.

The `load` procedure is *not* standardized for R6RS; here it is implementation-specific, and  the particulars depend upon the implementation. For Chez Scheme, `load` returns an *unspecified value*, so there should be no expectation of seeing anything useful when a file is successfully loaded.

Both R5RS and R7RS have `load` procedures described in the standards, but both leave it unspecified whether the results of evaluating the expressions in a file are printed.

The details of any script mechanism for Scheme programs is entirely dependent upon the implementation. But, when you run a script from the command-line your are not in a REPL, so again there should be no expectation that the results of evaluating various forms in the file will be printed to the terminal window.

If you want a Scheme file or script to print something, you have to make it do that. If the final line of the posted file is changed to `(display (numofatoms '((1 3) 7 (4(5 2))))) (newline)`, the program will display the result of calling `numofatoms` whenever it is run.